# Load layout depending on fragment witdth instead of screen width

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources

In my app, I have multiple fragments which are used within several activities. Depending on the screen size, the activities use different layouts in which their fragments may be stacked vertically and / or horizontally, tiled in a table like layout with rows and columns, or displayed nearly fullscreen under a tab bar.

For each fragment, there are also multiple layouts, for example

1. `res/`**`layout`**`/articles_list_fragment.xml`
2. `res/`**`layout-w590dp`**`/articles_list_fragment.xml`

In my fragment class, I'm loading the layout like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.articles_list_fragment, container, false);
    // (...)
}
```

Now, of course, when the fragment has less then 590dp width available to it, I'd want it to use the first layout, and when there is more than (or exactly) 590dp width available to the fragment, I want the second layout to be used.

But the android resource system seems to load those layout based only on the width 
[that is available to my whole activity window](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts). This does not suit my needs. For example, when my activity window is 1024dp wide, the left fragment will get 2/5 of that width, which makes 409dp. Anyway, the second layout resource is loaded, which needs 590dp width.

Of course, in this simple example, I could compute the exact activity window width at which my left fragment reaches 590dp: `590dp * 5 / 2 = 1475dp` and thus rename `res/`**`layout-w590dp`**`/articles_list_fragment.xml` to `res/`**`layout-w1475dp`**`/articles_list_fragment.xml`. However, in my real world case, the relation between activity window width and fragment width is much more complex, and statically / manually determine the minimum widths seems inappropriate.

So now I'm wondering if there is any kind of setting / hack / library / qualifier syntax that I can use to alter the way that android determines the resource it loads.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and got the impression that Android intentionally wants to force the developer to design the full screen layout (including all fragments) for each screen size, instead of layouting fragments in dependence of the fragment size.

Finally I decided to solve this issue by not reusing identical fragments for differently sized places. Instead, I was subclassing my fragment, overriding the onCreateView method, so that I can inflate different layouts for different sub-fragments.

Unfortunately, this was leading to duplications of layouts. In order to avoid this, one may do the workaround to put all layouts directly under the layout folder and determine the correct layout version out of the screen dimensions programmatically.